# SwipeRefreshLayout hiding part of last ListView item

Tags: android, swiperefreshlayout

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.partyspottr.appdir.ui.mainfragments.eventchildfragments.alle_eventer_fragment">

<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/swipe_layout_events"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_8sdp"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_8sdp"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_5sdp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/search_alle_eventer"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lvalle_eventer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:divider="@color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="@dimen/_20sdp"
        android:scrollbarSize="@dimen/_3sdp"
        android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@color/lightred"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/search_alle_eventer"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_8sdp"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_8sdp"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_90sdp"
    android:background="@drawable/border_rounded"
    android:hint="Search.."
    android:inputType="text"
    android:paddingEnd="@dimen/_10sdp"
    android:paddingStart="@dimen/_10sdp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="@dimen/_15ssp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/swipe_layout_events"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/swipe_layout_events"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

This is my layout XML, containing a parent (ConstraintLayout), a SwipeRefreshLayout with a ListView as child, and an EditText which i use to search items inside the ListView.

This layout is used as a fragment, so i have a button outside of this layout, when i press this button, the EditText either shows or doesn't, i do this with this code:

```
search_alle_eventer.setVisibility(search_alle_eventer.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE ? View.INVISIBLE : View.VISIBLE);
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = search_alle_eventer.getLayoutParams();

                if(search_alle_eventer.getVisibility() == View.INVISIBLE)
                    params.height = 0;
                else {
                    params.height = WRAP_CONTENT;

                    search_alle_eventer.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Now, the problem im having is when the EditText is showing (WRAP_CONTENT), when i scroll to the bottom of the ListView, the last item is cut off. How can i fix this?

Comment: set your editText in the xml how you want it when it is visible i.e `WRAP_CONTENT` .. or whatever, then in your logic set it between `View.GONE` or `View.VISIBLE` - don't mess with the params at all - the rest of the view isn't redrawn when you mess the params in this way, so your `0dp` height from the xml is what the `ListView` is rendered against.

Comment: @MarkKeen Since im using this layout as a fragment, when i use the constant `View.GONE` the whole SwipeRefreshLayout + ListView is pushed up behind the parent activity toolbar. That's why i used `View.INVISIBLE` and `View.VISIBLE` and `WRAP_CONTENT`..

Comment: `SwipeRefreshLayout + ListView is pushed up behind the parent activity toolbar` - well that's an issue with the container (`FrameLayout`) that the `Fragment` is in, that should be anchored below the toolbar, or have top margin of `android:attr/actionBarSize`

Answer (score 0):

you can set margin from bottom to ListView. `android:marginBottom = "50dp"`

Or try with relative layout like this

```
< RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.partyspottr.appdir.ui.mainfragments.eventchildfragments.alle_eventer_fragment">

<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
android:id="@+id/swipe_layout_events"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_8sdp"
android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_8sdp"
android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_5sdp"
>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lvalle_eventer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:divider="@color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="@dimen/_20sdp"
    android:scrollbarSize="@dimen/_3sdp"
    android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@color/lightred"
     />
    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

   <EditText
android:id="@+id/search_alle_eventer"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_8sdp"
android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_8sdp"
android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_90sdp"
android:background="@drawable/border_rounded"
android:hint="Search.."
android:inputType="text"
android:paddingEnd="@dimen/_10sdp"
android:paddingStart="@dimen/_10sdp"
android:textColor="@android:color/black"
android:textSize="@dimen/_15ssp"
 />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Which view are you reffering to?

Comment: I did not experience any difference, it is still cut off.
Also, did you mean `android:layout_marginBottom`?

Comment: this is a terrible idea

Comment: Can you try it with relative layout as I updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

Alright, thanks for you help, but my case is a special needs case, whatever im doing, im sure is not the correct way, but i'll let it be.

Fixed it by adding some more code inside the OnClickListener of the button i mentioned:

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        if(search_alle_eventer.getVisibility() == View.INVISIBLE)
                            listView.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
                        else
                            listView.setPadding(0, 0, 0, search_alle_eventer.getHeight());
                    }
                }, 100);
```

Adding some padding on the ListView whenever the EditText is visible did the trick for me.

EDIT: Thank you Mark Keen for pointing out the container for the fragments, I was being retarded not thinking straight. I fixed it by resizing the container.
Tbh, sorry for this question.